# How to create a claim based authorisation system implemented using role names? ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my application I have seeded users into my application as well as some data, but now I'm trying to create a system in which I can assign a user a role. I think this could be achieved through claim based authorization system using the claims system in ASP.NET Identity or to use role names, I am a bit confused at which approach to take and how to get there.

Currently I've created a way to seed users and to seed contacts but I read about `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` which I think is the correct way but again I'm not sure.

```
 public static class DbInit
  {
    public static void SeedDb(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        SeedPosts(context);
        SeedUsers(userManager);
    }

    private static void SeedUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = "Member1@email.com",
            Email = "Member1@email.com"

        };

        userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123!").Wait();
    }

    private static void SeedContacts(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();             
          context.Contact.Add(
            new Contact() { }

            );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`UserManager.AddToRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addtoroleasync) to add a role to a user. When the user signs in again, the role will automatically be added as a role claim.

Comment: @poke yeah but how do I set roles, so like admin, regular users, customer users, and give them like different access as such?

Comment: You have to create your roles once (using the `RoleManager` or using database seeding) so the role definitions exist. That allows you to add roles to users. As for protecting things based on a role, you can use the `[Authorize]` attribute or custom policies to enable [role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2). What a role is allowed to do is totally up to you.

Comment: @poke so which way is easier? what is a simple method I could to do Different users have different levels of authorisation,

Comment: @poke so in my seedUsers method should I add userManager.AddToRole(something).wait();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating roles, try

```
var userRole = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("User"));
```

For assign claims to roles, try

```
var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("User");
var roleClaims = await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim("area", "public1"));
```

For adding role to user, try

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
var roleToUser = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
```

It seems you did not define async method, you could try `_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User").Wait()`